# variable width button layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, border

I'm currently trying to make a button with a border around it. This border however needs a different width on different sides, for example 10px on left and rigt and 5px on top and bottom.
I've managed to create a rectangle with a 10px border using shape. Code is below. My question is how can I decrease the border width on arbitrary sides?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:endColor="#7A7A7A"
               android:angle="270" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
           <stroke android:width="10px" android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following.

```
<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”utf-8″?>
<selector xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android&#8221; >

<item android:state_pressed=”true” >
<shape>
<solid
android:color=”#4F3A1F” />
<stroke
 android:width=”1dp”
android:color=”#343434″ />
<corners
android:radius=”3dp” />
<padding
android:left=”5dp”
android:top=”5dp”
android:right=”5dp”
android:bottom=”5dp” />
</shape>
</item>
<item>
<shape>
<gradient
 android:startColor=”#453422″
android:endColor=”#956C36″
android:angle=”270″ />
 <stroke
 android:width=”0dp”
android:color=”#171717″ />
<corners
android:radius=”4dp” />
 <padding
 android:left=”5dp”
 android:top=”5dp”
 android:right=”5dp”
android:bottom=”5dp” />
</shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

Comment: The above code allowed me to do what I wanted by changing the padding of the first item. But I have trouble understanding why this is working. Could you elaborate?

Comment: ok,if it was working fine for you please accept the answer to support

Comment: I figured it out by myself now. I will accept the answer because it has helped me but you could have been a bit more informative instead of just posting a bunch of code...

Comment: thank you.sorry to say actually i don't have enough time to explain.i am busy with my work.